# Carriage return in to_char in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to cast a date in week / year format using to_char. Here's what my code looked like in 2017, when I didn't need to add the year at the end.

```
to_char(cast("minDate"as date), 
CASE WHEN 'datetype' = 'Weekly' 
THEN ('iw')
```

Now i'm trying to add the year on the next line (for display reasons), so here's the code that I tried.

```
to_char(cast("minDate"as date), 
CASE WHEN 'datetype' = 'Weekly' 
THEN ('iw\nyy')
```

it gives me this as a result (for february 2017)

```
02\\n17
```

I also tried the following

```
to_char(cast("minDate"as date), 
CASE WHEN 'datetype' = 'Weekly' 
THEN ('iw' + CHAR(13) + 'yy')
```

I can't seem to be able to make it work. Any help is appreciated !
The queries are made with PostgreSQL and a non-relational DB is used at the back.

Comment: Did you try `\n`

Comment: I'm not sure that `TO_CHAR` in your database (you never told us which DB you are using) will accept that format mask.  But in any case, your SQL tool may not be rendering the carriage return anyway.  So, it may already be working, or not.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: *SQL* is a query language, not a string *formatting* language. Displaying data like this is the job of the client/reporting tool. Why don't you do such formatting using client code?